# Organize headings by literal hierarchy or importance'?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics

I want to be accurate semantically and legible for screen-readers.

I'm wondering about this particular situation... 
I have a structure like:

```
Current Promotion:
-Promotion Title

Recent Blog Posts:
-BlogPost Title
-BlogPost TItle
```

Stylistically and for better reading, I think that the titles of the individual items should be larger than the section titles, which are basically organizational.. not going to get anyone too excited.

So I'm wondering if I should have the individual titles be h2s and the section headings be h3s based on 'importance' or leave it the reverse based on literal hierarchy?

It may not be a major issue, but I'm not sure what the right course of action is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headings should reflect hierarchy:

From [WebAIM](http://webaim.org/techniques/semanticstructure/), a useful accessibility resource:

> Pages should be structured in a hierarchical manner, with 1st degree headings () being the most important (usually page titles or heading), then 2nd degree headings ( - usually major section headings), down to 3rd degree headings (sub-sections of the ), and so on.

Some screenreaders - such as NVDA - present a structured list of headings to the end-user; if you have H2's within H3's, then the list will get messed up, and will instead look like your H3 section headers are actually sub-sections from the previous content:

```
Current Promotion:

Promotion Title
- Recent Blog Posts:

BlogPost Title
BlogPost TItle
```

Comment: +1, headings should definitely reflect page hierarchy. Also, @Damon could always resize his headings for sighted users to get the effect he wants, e.g. `h2 { font-size: 1.2em; } h3 { font-size: 1.4em; }`, so that section titles are visually smaller than individual items.

Comment: thanks! all I needed to know and glad that it does matter afterall :)